# Codename One Graphics call Method

Tags: class, graphics, codenameone

I am making my first learning steps with CN1 graphics.

I encounter difficulties when calling the paint method of the following class in the start () method.

```
public class DrawingCanvas extends Component {

     public void myMethod(Graphics g) {

        // some code
    }

}
```

In the start() method, I call the method like this:

```
 public void start() {

     DrawingCanvas drawingCanvas = new DrawingCanvas();           
     drawingCanvas.myMethod(g);

 }
```

The error message I get is : Cannot find symbol : variable g

In my understanding, I now have to define g somehow.

How do I do that?

```
 Graphics g =
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't and don't initialize graphics. Graphics is created internally within Codename One and passed to the `paint` method as a callback. You should never invoke `paint(Graphics)` on your own.

If you want to invoke `paint(Graphics)` you can invoke `cmp.repaint()` which will call paint for you. Notice that you don't need to invoke it normally as paint is implicitly invoked when needed e.g. when layout changes etc.

Comment: Shai, Thank you. I don't know, if my question is clear. How do I call the public void paint(Graphics g) from another class in the start method? Don't I have to initialize Graphics somehow? I can't do : start (Graphics g)... Does your answer mean I should initialize Graphics in the start method like this : Graphic g = cmp.repaint() ? What would cmp be, by the way?

Comment: `paint` is a method of `Component` that you can override. It's invoked for you, it's a callback like `start()`. You don't need to invoke `paint(Graphics) just like you don't need to invoke it for button or [label](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/ui/Label.java#L553-L560). Notice in the label class when we need to paint due to changes in the class we just invoke repaint() and the system does the rest...

Comment: I guess I know where the misunderstanding comes from. It's probably the paint method. I have edited the question to make it clearer. How do I call any method in start() that contains (Graphics g)? I have to tell the system somehow what the variable g is, am I right? I have to define the variable like so: Graphics g = ..........  (correct me if I'm wrong). )How do I do that?

Comment: No. You don't. Paint will be invoked on its own. Just like you never invoke `Label.paint(Graphics)` and yet it's invoked and runs. `paint(Graphics)` is invoked implicitly and indirectly. You can request a paint by invoking `repaint()` at which point our system will perform the paint for you. Just add `DrawingCanvas` to the center of a border layout form and show the form.